# Flexbox Container with three DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, flexbox

I have a flexbox with two elements which should be next to each other. The first DIV have a static width of 350px. The second DIV is dynamic. The width depends on the content.

Now I create a third DIV which content is also dynamic. But this DIV should be limited to the end of the second DIV. So the content should wrap to the width where the second DIV ends.

```
.out {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.infos {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-basis: 350px;
}
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1 1;
}
.third {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

<div class="out">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="infos">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    accusam et justo duo dolores et earebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem    ipsum dolor sit a
  </div>
</div>
```

I know: In this example the third DIV is out of the flexbox, but I think the solution connects to the flexbox.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ymx9oog/9/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You already have this in your jsfiddle:

```
.outRow {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Why not add it to `row` and maybe a `margin: 10px` for `third` and I guess that would do:

**EDIT**:

One thing you can do is remove the `flex: 1` from `dynamic` and wrap the contents of the `third` into an absolute container relative to it:

```
.third {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 10px;
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.third div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You will have to specify the `height` for `third` if you go with this option.

```css
.out {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.outRow {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.infos {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 350px;
}
.dynamic {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.third {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 10px;
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.third div{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out outRow">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="infos">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">
    Lorem ipsum 
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="third">
      <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: With your code the blue box in the fiddle is too big. The blue box should end with the content. Then the third box should be limited to the end of the blue box. The text in the third box can be wrapped.